# Obter o valor da "option" que foi clicada quer para selecionar/desselecionar

Tags: javascript, jquery

tenho o seguinte `<select>`:

```
<select id="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="pedra">Pedra</option>
  <option value="papel">Papel</option>
  <option value="tesoura">Tesoura</option>
</select>
```

Com o código Jquery abaixo, consigo obter o valor do último `<option>` selecionado:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#multiselect').multiselect();

    $(document).on('change','#multiselect', function(){

        console.log (( $('option', this).filter(':selected:last').val() ))
    });
  });
</script>
```

Porém, o que eu queria de verdade, era obter o valor do `<option>` clicado (sei que `on('click', func..)` não funcionará neste caso), independente se está sendo selecionado ou desselecionado.

Pesquisei bastante, mas o máximo que encontrei, foi como encontrar o valor do último selecionado.

O plugin utilizado é o [Bootstrap-multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect)

Comment: Não sei ao certo se é isto que pretendes, mas vê este [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/R4egw/) com um exemplo daquilo que me parece ser o que procuras.

Comment: @Zull, o conceito é exatamente este. Li a documentação do plugin, e adaptei. Obrigado por ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## RESOLVIDO

Pessoal, obrigado pela atenção de vocês. O plugin que estou usando é o [Bootstrap-Multiselect.](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) Não sei se existe uma solução mais elegante e melhor, mas, consegui resolver assim:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#multiselect').multiselect({
    onChange: function(element, checked) {
      console.log(element[0]['value']);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Você pode marcar sua resposta como aceita aí do lado esquerdo.

Comment: Só após dois dias. =)

Answer (score 6):

Tente usar assim:

```
$('#multiselect').multiselect();
$("#multiselect").on("multiselectclick", function (event, ui) {
    console.log(ui.value);
});
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/6zrVG/)

Encontrei isto [**na documentação**](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget):

> ```
> $("#multiselect").on("multiselectclick", function(event, ui) {
>   /* event: the original event object
>      ui.value: value of the checkbox
>      ui.text: text of the checkbox
>      ui.checked: whether or not the input was checked or unchecked (boolean)
>   */
> });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Para conseguir o efeito que espera, você precisa colocar um *handler* para cada elemento *option*:

```
$("#multiselect").on("click", "option", function() {
    var clickedOption = $(this);
    alert(clickedOption.val());
});
```

Exemplo do código em funcionamento:

http://jsfiddle.net/ryNFE/2/

Exemplo com console.log (sem o alert):

```
$("#multiselect").on("click", "option", function() {
    var clickedOption = $(this);
    console.log(clickedOption.val());
});
```

Comment: Nesse código se você segurar o `ctrl` para desmarcar o item, ele vai dar o alerta também.

Comment: @GabrielGartz então você precisa mudar sua pergunta:


"Porém, o que eu queria de verdade, era obter o valor do <option> clicado (sei que on('click', func..) não funcionará neste caso), **independente** se está sendo selecionado ou desselecionado."

Comment: @GabrielGartz então não consegui entender qual o problema, se a solução retorna exatamente o que você pediu na pergunta.

Comment: @OniltonMaciel A pergunta foi colocada pelo Eric Vieira. Penso que o Gabriel Gartz está apenas a alertar para um detalhe na tua solução que pode causar algum transtorno.

Comment: Ok, confusão minha, achei que era o autor. Obrigado pelo esclarezimento @Zuul. De qualquer forma, só para esclarecer, segurando o ctrl aqui (para mim pelo menos), não causa o evento de click por si só. A não ser que você faça Ctrl+Click. Mas nesse caso você está efetuando um click e ação deve ser ativada, "independente se o item está sendo selecionado ou desselecionado", conforme requisitado na pergunta.

Comment: Pessoa, consegui resolver. Peço desculpas por não ter informado de cara qual plugin estava a utilizar. De qualquer maneira, o conceito era exatamente o apresentado pelo @OniltonMaciel e pelo Zuul